# Electronically controlled variable AC-AC and DC-AC

Tags: power-supply, transformer, ac, inverter, dc-ac

I've seen devices (and saw answered questions) that are somewhat similar to what I want to do but I haven't found exactly what I'm looking for.  I want to control a power supply with my Raspberry Pi and have it output variable AC current from 0-35 VAC at up to 10 amps or so.  It would take normal 110vac input.  I'll write a program that will slowly ramp up the voltage to 35VAC on startup, and slowly ramp down the voltage on shutdown or high temperature condition.  Currently, I'm using a Variac, which is completely manual.  The only automatic component is that the Raspberry Pi will trigger a relay, cutting power completely in the event of a high temperature condition.

I may be interested in a second device that is basically a variable inverter.  I have solar panels and a few kWh of lithium ion batteries so if I can control an inverter's output voltage in the same way I described the AC-AC device above, that would be nice as well.  My battery voltage is 21-24 VDC.  If I had to pick, the AC-AC device is more important because I know I'd be able to keep my machine running indefinitely.

Comment: use a servo to turn the variac

Comment: Use a transformer after the Variac to step the voltage down to 35 V, then use a motor to drive the Variac.  Using the step-down transformer ensures you won't get excessive voltage if the motor drive does bad things.

Comment: Thank you both for your responses.  That's definitely a viable option (especially using the transformer to prevent exceeding 35V by the servo).  But if a pure sine wave inverter can do it electronically, how come there aren't any AC-AC devices that do the same thing?  I suppose I could go AC to DC and then back to AC but then I'm still not aware of a variable output inverter, though it's definitely possible.  My solar battery solution could skip the AC-DC part and go right to the inverter.

Comment: Inverters such as these (https://www.ato.com/pure-sine-wave-inverters) have a wide range of output voltages.  So it seems very likely that an electronic solution could exist for what I want to do.  These inverters have 100/110/120/220/230/240VAC output.  I could use discrete voltages as well.  It doesn't have to be smooth from 0-35.  In fact, it doesn't really have to start at 0.  Something like this would work: 10 / 12 / 14 / 16 / 18 / 20 / 22 / 24 / 26 / 28 / 30 /  32 / 34 / 35

Comment: your comments indicate that you are asking which device to buy ... such a question is not allowed here ... this site is for questions about designing a device like that

Comment: I apologize.  I wasn't aware of that.  So, if someone were creating their own buck converter (for example), are people not allowed to recommend a particular inductor for that DC-DC converter?  I'm not simply shopping for a single device that will take care of my whole solution.  I'm still engineering the voltage regulation, as a whole.  An inverter would only be one component of it.  If that's not allowed, I can delete this question.

Comment: Any recommendation on the mosfets, capacitors, etc, that I would need to build my own pure sine wave inverter circuit capable of 10A?  I would say 15A to be safe.  Maybe use an arduino for the PWM?  I might just take the plunge and try to build this whole thing from the ground up.

Comment: you just need an audio amplifier and a 60hz source wave.

Comment: Thanks dandavis!  That never occurred to me.  This is for a cryocooler that needs 60 Hz so I could just play a continuous 60 Hz sound through it and if I can adjust the volume externally, that would change the voltage.  As long as it can maintain 10-11 amps at a 34-35 volt amplitude, it will work.  I will look into this idea.

Comment: That sounds like a 350-400W amplifier. I would look at used car audio amps (run the stereo output in parallel)  or used mono PA amps for a turnkey "module". I would actually go higher than 400W if it's rated for 8 ohm speakers, do the ohms law math to make sure it's compatible with your I/V curve.